# How to assign a boolean value under the onclick method of android?

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton

I have booleans `i` and 'j'.

I want to have one method when only image "two" is clicked.
And other method when image "two" is clicked after image "one" is clicked.
Please help sir. I am in trouble.

How do I get the return value from onclick method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    boolean I,j;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView one=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final ImageView two=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        i=false;
           j=false;
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i=true;
            }
        }); 
            two.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                   @Override
                   public void onclick(View v){ 
                          j=true;

                       }

        if (i){
            three.setImageResource(R.drawable.green1);
        }
            if(j){
                    three.setImageResourse(R.drawable.red1)
         }
           if(I==true&& j==true)
                 three.setImageResoure(R.drawable.yellow1)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to show image on button click >??

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you do not understand the flow of the code that you have written.

Step by step:

1. The App starts. `i` is uninitialized.
2. The `Activity` is created `i` is set to false.
3. The `OnClickListener` is set for your `ImageView`.
4. The if statement is fired to check `i`. It is false (at this point it can only ever be false).
5. At some point, you click on the `ImageView` and `i` becomes true.

You could happily move your `two.setImageResource(R.drawable.green1);` line into the body of the `onClick(View v)` function.

So that it looks like this:

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        two.setImageResource(R.drawable.green1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      i=true;
      if (i){
        //if you want change vale to false (i = false)
        two.setImageResource(R.drawable.green1);
      }

});
```

Comment: Please tell us more about this code. You provided an answer that has no obvious connection to the question asked. While it may be a good answer, it requires explanation, why.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView one=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final ImageView two=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                two.setImageResource(R.drawable.green1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```